# AceFEM: Session Identifier

Tags: acegen

I wonder wether there is a way to identify an AceFEM session. Some variable with a Hash or the startup time of the current session, which is reset after an SMTInputData[] command. 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `SMTSession[[51, 1]]` is set to `AbsoluteTime[]` every time when `SMTInputData[]` is called. This can be probably used as unique identifier of AceFEM session.

```
<< AceFEM`;
SMTInputData[];
id = SMTSession[[51, 1]]
(* 3.7204563945580672*10^9 *)

DateString@FromAbsoluteTime@id
(* "Thu 23 Nov 2017 20:06:34" *)
```

Be aware that this solution is undocumented.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response Pinti (y)